# Flutter: Errors related to WidgetsBinding and callbacks when implementing honeywell package

Tags: android, flutter, dart, honeywell

I was able to implement this flutter package: https://pub.dev/packages/honeywell_scanner

I am now trying to use the examples that are provided here: https://pub.dev/packages/honeywell_scanner/example

The problem is that my IDE is showing errors pointing to 3 lines (noted below). I just started a new flutter project, so there is nothing overly complex going on in it. The app only consists of `main.dart` which opens `scan.dart`.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:honeywell_scanner/honeywell_scanner.dart';

```
class Scan extends StatefulWidget {
  const Scan({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Scan> createState() => _ScanState();
}

class _ScanState extends State<Scan> {
//...//
@override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this); //Error here: The argument type '_ScanState' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'WidgetsBindingObserver'.
    honeywellScanner.scannerCallback = this; //Error here: A value of type '_ScanState' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'ScannerCallback'.
    initialize();
  }

@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state); //Error here: Superclass has no method named 'didChangeAppLifecycleState'.
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        honeywellScanner.resumeScanner();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        honeywellScanner.pauseScanner();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState
          .paused: //AppLifecycleState.paused is used as stopped state because deactivate() works more as a pause for lifecycle
        honeywellScanner.pauseScanner();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        honeywellScanner.pauseScanner();
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  //...//
```

Answer (score 0):

Was missing the following:

```
class _ScanState extends State<Scan>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver
    implements ScannerCallback {...
```

and then for the `didChangeAppLifecycleState` I just removed `super.`